# Facebook, Twitter & Google integration using socialauth

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, socialauth

I am building an android app that connects to facebook, twitter and google for user logins. I am getting the following error -

```
org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Unable to retrieve the access token. Status: 400. Could not connect using SocialAuth
```

The code is as follows -

```
package com.opaxlabs.boatbrat;

import org.brickred.socialauth.Profile;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.DialogListener;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthListener;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter.Provider;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        adapter=new SocialAuthAdapter(new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
                Log.e("Login activity", arg0.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle arg0) {
                adapter.getUserProfileAsync(new SocialAuthListener<Profile>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onExecute(String arg0, Profile arg1) {
                        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Receiving Data");
                           Profile profileMap = arg1;
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Validate ID         = " + profileMap.getValidatedId());
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "First Name          = " + profileMap.getFirstName());
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Last Name           = " + profileMap.getLastName());
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Email               = " + profileMap.getEmail());
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Gender                   = " + profileMap.getGender());
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Country                  = " + profileMap.getCountry());
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Language                 = " + profileMap.getLanguage());
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Location                 = " + profileMap.getLocation());
                           Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Profile Image URL  = " + profileMap.getProfileImageURL());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onBack() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
//        adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);
//        adapter.addProvider(Provider.GOOGLE, R.drawable.google);
//        adapter.addProvider(Provider.TWITTER, R.drawable.twitter);
        Button skip=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSkip);
        skip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageView imgFacebook=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imgFacebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.authorize(LoginActivity.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);
            }
        });
        ImageView imgGoogle=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imgGoogle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.addCallBack(Provider.GOOGLE,"http://socialauth.in/socialauthdemo");
                adapter.authorize(LoginActivity.this, Provider.GOOGLE);
            }
        });
        ImageView imgTwitter=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imgTwitter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.addCallBack(Provider.TWITTER,"http://socialauth.in/socialauthdemo/socialAuthSuccessAction.do");
                adapter.authorize(LoginActivity.this, Provider.TWITTER);
            }
        });
    }



}
```

I have tried commenting and uncommenting the adapter.addprovider() lines but the problem persists. Facebook and Twitter work perfectly fine but there is some trouble with Google. I have added the client-id and api key that were generated in the credentials to oauth_consumer.properties.
Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: your net connection is oke right!!

Comment: I have added permissions for internet and network.

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, I am sure you have figured it out, would you share your full working  `LoginActivity` code over [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), I am also struggling with implementation of social auth for Twitter, FB & Google. It will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the correct callback url.